# Error Upgrading/Modifying Fabcar Chainicode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I wrote a script (see below) based on startFabric.sh to upgrade the fabcar chaincode. Basically, (1) I executed ./startFabric.sh, (2) modified the chaincode which is the fabcar.js file in the chaincodes folder, (3) ran my upgrade script (below), (4) cd javascript folder, (5) executed node query.js, and received error retrieving package and opening directory. What is wrong with my upgradeFabric.sh script?

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

# don't rewrite paths for Windows Git Bash users
export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1
starttime=$(date +%s)
CC_SRC_LANGUAGE=${1:-"go"}
CC_SRC_LANGUAGE=`echo "$CC_SRC_LANGUAGE" | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]`
if [ "$CC_SRC_LANGUAGE" = "go" -o "$CC_SRC_LANGUAGE" = "golang"  ]; then
    CC_RUNTIME_LANGUAGE=golang
    CC_SRC_PATH=github.com/chaincode/fabcar/go
elif [ "$CC_SRC_LANGUAGE" = "java" ]; then
    CC_RUNTIME_LANGUAGE=java
    CC_SRC_PATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode/fabcar/java
elif [ "$CC_SRC_LANGUAGE" = "javascript" ]; then
    CC_RUNTIME_LANGUAGE=node # chaincode runtime language is node.js
    CC_SRC_PATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode/fabcar/javascript
elif [ "$CC_SRC_LANGUAGE" = "typescript" ]; then
    CC_RUNTIME_LANGUAGE=node # chaincode runtime language is node.js
    CC_SRC_PATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode/fabcar/typescript
    echo Compiling TypeScript code into JavaScript ...
    pushd ../chaincode/fabcar/typescript
    npm install
    npm run build
    popd
    echo Finished compiling TypeScript code into JavaScript
else
    echo The chaincode language ${CC_SRC_LANGUAGE} is not supported by this script
    echo Supported chaincode languages are: go, javascript, and typescript
    exit 1
fi


# clean the keystore
rm -rf ./hfc-key-store

CONFIG_ROOT=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
ORG1_MSPCONFIGPATH=${CONFIG_ROOT}/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
ORG1_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=${CONFIG_ROOT}/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
ORG2_MSPCONFIGPATH=${CONFIG_ROOT}/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp
ORG2_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=${CONFIG_ROOT}/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt
ORDERER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=${CONFIG_ROOT}/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
set -x

echo "Installing smart contract on peer0.org1.example.com"
docker exec \
  -e CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP \
  -e CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051 \
  -e CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=${ORG1_MSPCONFIGPATH} \
  -e CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=${ORG1_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE} \
  cli \
  peer chaincode install \
    -n fabcar \
    -v 1.6 \
    -p "$CC_SRC_PATH" \
    -l "$CC_RUNTIME_LANGUAGE"

echo "Installing smart contract on peer0.org2.example.com"
docker exec \
  -e CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP \
  -e CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:9051 \
  -e CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=${ORG2_MSPCONFIGPATH} \
  -e CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=${ORG2_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE} \
  cli \
  peer chaincode install \
    -n fabcar \
    -v 1.6 \
    -p "$CC_SRC_PATH" \
    -l "$CC_RUNTIME_LANGUAGE"

echo "(1/2) Upgrading smart contract on mychannel"
docker exec \
  -e CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP \
  -e CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=${ORG1_MSPCONFIGPATH} \
  cli \
  peer chaincode upgrade \
    -o orderer.example.com:7050 \
    -C mychannel \
    -n fabcar \
    -l "$CC_RUNTIME_LANGUAGE" \
    -v 1.6 \
    -c '{"Args":[]}' \
    -P "AND('Org1MSP.member','Org2MSP.member')" \
    --tls \
    --cafile ${ORDERER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE} \
    --peerAddresses peer0.org1.example.com:7051 \
    --tlsRootCertFiles ${ORG1_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE}

echo "(2/2) Upgrading smart contract on mychannel"
docker exec \
  -e CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP \
  -e CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=${ORG2_MSPCONFIGPATH} \
  cli \
  peer chaincode upgrade \
    -o orderer.example.com:7050 \
    -C mychannel \
    -n fabcar \
    -l "$CC_RUNTIME_LANGUAGE" \
    -v 1.6 \
    -c '{"Args":[]}' \
    -P "AND('Org1MSP.member','Org2MSP.member')" \
    --tls \
    --cafile ${ORDERER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE} \
    --peerAddresses peer0.org2.example.com:9051 \
    --tlsRootCertFiles ${ORG2_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE}

echo "Waiting for upgrade request to be committed ..."
sleep 10

echo "Submitting initLedger transaction to smart contract on mychannel"
echo "The transaction is sent to the two peers with the chaincode installed (peer0.org1.example.com and peer0.org2.example.com) so that chaincode is built before receiving the following requests"
docker exec \
  -e CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP \
  -e CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=${ORG1_MSPCONFIGPATH} \
  cli \
  peer chaincode invoke \
    -o orderer.example.com:7050 \
    -C mychannel \
    -n fabcar \
    -c '{"function":"initLedger","Args":[]}' \
    --waitForEvent \
    --tls \
    --cafile ${ORDERER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE} \
    --peerAddresses peer0.org1.example.com:7051 \
    --peerAddresses peer0.org2.example.com:9051 \
    --tlsRootCertFiles ${ORG1_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE} \
    --tlsRootCertFiles ${ORG2_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE}
set +x

cat <<EOF

Total setup execution time : $(($(date +%s) - starttime)) secs ...

EOF
```

And this is the error when executing node query.js...

```
allet path: /home/seans/go/src/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/wallet
2020-06-20T00:08:33.951Z - warn: [Query]: evaluate: Query ID "[object Object]" of peer "peer1.org1.example.com:8051" failed: message=cannot retrieve package for chaincode fabcar/1.6, error open /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes/fabcar.1.6: no such file or directory, stack=Error: cannot retrieve package for chaincode fabcar/1.6, error open /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes/fabcar.1.6: no such file or directory
    at self._endorserClient.processProposal (/home/seans/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Peer.js:144:36)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/seans/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1212:9)
    at InterceptingListener._callNext (/home/seans/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:568:42)
    at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/home/seans/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:618:8)
    at callback (/home/seans/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:847:24), status=500, , url=grpcs://localhost:8051, name=peer1.org1.example.com:8051, grpc.max_receive_message_length=-1, grpc.max_send_message_length=-1, grpc.keepalive_time_ms=120000, grpc.http2.min_time_between_pings_ms=120000, grpc.keepalive_timeout_ms=20000, grpc.http2.max_pings_without_data=0, grpc.keepalive_permit_without_calls=1, name=peer1.org1.example.com:8051, grpc.ssl_target_name_override=peer1.org1.example.com, grpc.default_authority=peer1.org1.example.com, isProposalResponse=true
Failed to evaluate transaction: Error: cannot retrieve package for chaincode fabcar/1.6, error open /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes/fabcar.1.6: no such file or directory
```

Comment: I have couple of questions:

1. Why are you upgrading the smart contract just after installing it? Directly install the updated Smart contract since you haven't instantiated it.

2. When you are upgrading the smart-contract, you need to update the CC version too. In your case it's `1.6`. for up-gradation too, make it `1.7`.

3. your node.js query script trying to query `peer1.org1` but it's unable to find cc package. To fix this, you need to install CC package on `peer1.org1`.

Comment: you can follow this script: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/v1.4.3/first-network/scripts/utils.sh

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a couple of things.

- Check to see if you're using the 2.X release of Fabric (v2.1.1 is the latest stable version at the moment).  It has the new lifecycle functionality which will make working with chaincode a lot easier.  For instance, with the new lifecycle, installing and upgrading a chaincode follows the same process and commands, you use `peer lifecycle chaincode install` to install and/or upgrade a chaincode.
- The overall flow to deploy chaincode becomes pretty straightforward (1) package the chaincode, (2) install it on your peers, (3) approve the chaincode definition for your organization, and (4) commit the definition to your channel.
- You can use the [test-network tutorial](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/test_network.html) to get set up with 2.X, it takes you through the complete network and chaincode set up.  Look at [network.sh](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/test-network/network.sh) and [deployCC.sh](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/test-network/scripts/deployCC.sh) scripts from the tutorial for details on how to work with Chaincode.

Further Reading

- The [upgrade process with new lifecycle](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/chaincode_lifecycle.html#upgrade-a-chaincode) based chaincode mgmt.
- [Blog on deploying CC](https://medium.com/@robmurgai/finally-hyperledger-fabric-made-easy-with-a-new-test-network-iv-e11f82d906ec) with Fabric 2.X based on the test-network.